# How to set up PATH in order to run the the program

Tags: macos, makefile

I have a program called "PeakSplitter" that is executed by another program called "MACS". Following by the installation instruction, I have successfully installed "PeakSplitter" except the last step, which I didn't know how to do it. Here is the instruction.

1. Open up a command terminal, go to the directory "PeakSplitter_v1" where you have uncompressed PeakSplitter.
2. Within this directory, go to "SFL/Release" directory and run the makefile using 
   make (or make -f makefile)
3. Return to the directory "PeakSplitter_v1", then go to the "Zlib/Release" directory and run the makefile
   make (or make -f makefile)
4. Now you are ready to install PeakSplitter. Return to the directory "PeakSplitter_v1", and run the makefile
   make (or make -f makefile)
   An executable file named "PeakSplitter" will be generated in this folder.
5. To run the program type ./PeakSplitter, and ./PeakSplitter --help in order to get some help on the input parameters.
6. You can move the "PeakSplitter" exe file to anywhere on your file system and set the PATH to this folder.

I think I have to move the "PeakSplitter" exe file to the MACS file system and set the PATH. Can anyone teach me how to do it?
Thank you very much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting environment variables in OS X?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x)

Comment: `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/peaksplitter`

Comment: Well, if I run the peaksplitter under MACS folder, it works. but If I run MACS with argument of peaksplitter, it still gives me error: no such file or directory. Any idea what went wrong?